# LotusScript - Is it possible to create check mark near document in view?

Tags: lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

Is there any way to generate check mark near selected document by using LotusScript or @-formulas in the view:

[image]

I have already tried this:

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    Set docByUi = uiDoc.Document
    Set uiView = ws.CurrentView
    If docByUi.selectedCreatorsIDs(0) <> "" Then
        Forall docID In docByUi.selectedCreatorsIDs
            Call uiView.SelectDocument(db.Getdocumentbyunid(docID))
        End Forall
        'Call ws .ViewRefresh
    End If
```

It's working and I am selecting all docs I want, but the check mark in the left panel isn't shown.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an formula agent of type ["Select documents in view"](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/d6091795dfaa5b1185256a7a0048a2d0/54ff5e449824161c85257751005e77e1?OpenDocument) and add a SELECT formula that returns true for documents you want to be selected in view with a check mark.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this is what I have wanted!